# PHP : Get key of an array that matches specific value

Tags: php, arrays, function, key

Here is how I set my Array:

```
 $Post_Cat_Array = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 $Post_Cat_Array[$row['type_id']] = $row['type_name'];}
```

in this function I need to get the `type_id`(key) of a specific `type_name`(value)

```
function NameToID($input){
echo array_search($input, $Post_Cat_Array); 
}
```

and I call the function like this :

```
NameToID($_POST['type']);
```

But it's not working. It doesn't echo anything. I am sure the `$_POST['type']` contains correct value.

note:value of `$_POST['type']` is in arabic. same with all values of the array.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: what do you see when right after your SQL code you print the array with : print_r($Post_Cat_Array); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `$Post_Cat_Array` is out of scope. Modify your function:

```
function NameToID($input, $arr){
  echo array_search($input, $arr); 
}
```

and then:

```
NameToID($_POST['type'], $Post_Cat_Array);
```

From [PHP Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> This script will not produce any output because the echo statement
>   refers to a local version of the (...) variable, and it has not been
>   assigned a value within this scope.

Comment: I've edited my answer, there is a link to PHP docs about variable scope. Shortly: variables inside functions have different scope, so other (*outside*) variables are not accessible unless you pass them as parameters or mark them as a `global`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your array variable is not known to your function. You can use either of the following to achieve that

```
<?php
$Post_Cat_Array=array();
$Post_Cat_Array["key1"]="value1";
$Post_Cat_Array["key2"]="value2";
$Post_Cat_Array["key3"]="value3";
$Post_Cat_Array["key4"]="value4";

echo NameToID("value4");
echo "<br>";
echo NameToID2("value4",$Post_Cat_Array);

function NameToID($input){ 
    global $Post_Cat_Array;
    echo array_search($input, $Post_Cat_Array);  
} 
function NameToID2($input,$values){ 
    echo array_search($input, $values);  
} 
?>
```